# Cómo avanzar de uno en uno con un boton en un vector que me es mandado por un servicio?

Tags: angular, api

{ "Result": [ { "Alumno": "1" }, { "Alumno": "123" }, { "Alumno": "21312" }, { "Alumno": "534534" }, { "SINIIGA": "123456789123456789" } ], "intResponse": 200, "strAnswer": "Success" }

Estoy recibiendo esto desde una api, y quiero vincularla a un boton para que al momento de yo dar un clic, avance al siguiente método pero no sé muy bien como hacerlo en Angular.

Comment: Hola, que haz intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos